# Agent start a call when the previous is still in progress

Tags: firebird, overlap, firebird-3.0

I have a CALLS table with

```
CALL_ID | OPERATOR_ID |       CALL_START      |        CALL_END       | NOTES | TYPE
========+=============+=======================+=======================+=======+======
    101 |    3000     | '2020-12-12 08:00:00' | '2020-12-12 08:10:00' |  ...  | ...
    102 |    3000     | '2020-12-12 08:08:00' | '2020-12-12 08:20:00' |  ...  | ...
```

CALL_ID 102 has started before CALL_ID 101 has ended (for the same operator_ID).

I need to find calls where CALL_END > CALL_START (on the next row for the same operator) and I'm stuck.

Comment: What version of Firebird?  What should happen if multiple subsequent calls from the same operator overlap with a preceding call, though perhaps not with each other?  E.g., call 'A' from 08:00 – 08:30, 'B' from 08:05 – 08:15, 'C' from 08:10 – 08:20, and 'D' from 08:21 – 08:45 ?

Comment: Hi, FB 3.07 and all I need is to find those calls and point them out (adjust them if need be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the CALLS table against itself by OPERATOR_ID, looking for "right hand" call records with a CALL_START between any "left hand" call record's CALL_START and CALL_END:

```
SELECT c.operator_id,
       c.call_id,
       c.call_start,
       c.call_end,
       other.call_id,
       other.call_start
  FROM calls c
 INNER JOIN
       calls other
    ON c.operator_id = other.operator_id
 WHERE c.call_id != other.call_id
       AND
       other.call_start BETWEEN c.call_start AND c.call_end
```

Comment: thank you pilcrow, going to join and a couple of tables to give some names and job done. Thank you and Merry Xmas to you and everyone

Comment: very useful indeed pilcrow, and thank you again.

Comment: I wonder if anyone could help me converting this in an update to to change the call_end_operator to the other.call_start - 2 seconds..